# android studio disconnects when opening file

Tags: java, android-studio

I have the following code, in which I open a pdf file and it is selected:

```
        @Override
        public void onCotizacion(View view, int position) throws Exception {
            Otes item = listOtes.get(position);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Abriendo Documento");
            progressDialog.show();
            String nomDoc = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".pdf";
            /**DOC DE SOLO LECTURA*/
            File pdfFile = new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), nomDoc);
            logosData.open();
                        // Code
                        }
```

hen it goes through this event, that is, when I select a pdf file to open, the first time it works, but after the second or third time I choose it from the list it falls to the following line:

**File pdfFile = new File(getContext().getCacheDir(), DocName);**

It disconnects, and in debugging I get the following error:

**Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:64077', transport: 'socket'**

Maybe you have to clear the cache, or something similar. If anyone has any idea why it crashes or disconnects, I would appreciate your help, thank you in advance.
I attach an image to show where it disconnects
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVY8T.png)

Obs:It disconnects after passing 2 or 3, or four times when selecting the item from the list to see the pdf

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).